# Using two autocompeters with struts2 jquery

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, struts2, struts2-jquery

I need to solve a simple use case as below

There is a form which two autocompleters:

1. select city
2. select areas in that city

When we select a particular city I want to load areas of that city in area autocompleter.

```
    $.subscribe('citySelectTopic', function(event, data) {
        var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
        var message = ui.item.value;
        if(ui.item.key) {
            message = '( '+ ui.item.key +' ) '+message;
        }
        alert(message); // ? What more to write here?
    });

<s:url var="remoteurl123" action="loadCity" namespace="/"/>


<sj:autocompleter id="cityAutocompleter" dataType="json" href="%{remoteurl123}"
    loadMinimumCount="3" list="cities" listKey="id" 
    listValue="name" onSelectTopics="citySelectTopic"/>


<sj:autocompleter id="areaAutocompleter" list="cities" 
    listKey="id" listValue="name" reloadTopics="citySelectTopic" />
```

My loadCity action returns list of all cities with name entered - now onselectTopics to do following things but not able to know how

1. OnSelectTopics - load all areas in selected city - need to pass city id
2. OnSuccess of #1 - show the list of all areas returned in #areaAutocompleter

Could someone please help me in doing this?

Comment: They will come as json response as we select city via citySelectTopic? How to make a jquery ajax call on this?

Comment: You have to save it to the action first then call ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the example at showcase 
with the path Ajax -> Form -> Ajax Select (double select)

http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action

or download the showcase package and check the source.

Comment: The way we have select double select - can we have autocompelter double select.